# Google Chrome: Saved password does not allow to login the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, browser, authentication

I am using Chrome browser and facing an unusual scenario. When I login to my application with Chrome saved username and password it does not allow to login in the first attempt(submit/click of the login button). In the second attempt (submit/click) it allows to login. I don't face the same issue when using Firefox where also the username and password are stored in browser. It allows me to login successfully in the first attempt as desired.

Here's my login HTML:

```
<form id="loginForm" autocomplete="off"> 
<input type="text" id="username" />
<input type="password" id="password" />
</form>
<button id="submit">Sign In</button>
```

Here's the script which is called when I click on the submit button:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
    console.log($('#username').val());
    console.log($('#password').val());
    e.preventDefault();
    performLogin(); 
});

function performLogin() {
//Logic to validate the form and submit to server and process further
}
```

When I print the password in the console it gives a blank value when trying to login in the first attempt even though the password field is not blank. 
Can anyone explain how Chrome handles the saved username and password as I am unable to understand this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: "_in the first attempt(submit/click of the login button)_"  what does it say? I mean any error or the form just refreshes saying invalid login.

Comment: It asks me to enter the password again.  I am validating my username and password in the performLogin() method(client side validation for empty fields and length criteria etc..) and if it passes through a request is hit to the server for further process. The client side validation fails here in the first attempt. Hope I am clear.

Comment: So post your validation script... You said it yourself, it's the validation script that fails the first time. Try this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/yVoZJR?editors=1111) ;)

Comment: Why would you need the script? When I print the value of the password in the console as shown above before validation it shows blank and this happens only in Chrome.